# Web Service TEsting - Code Coverage

Tags: web-services, testing, code-coverage, emma

I'm using emma to testing coverage (applications, jsp pages, etc), but I can not do this with web services, is it possible with emma? or is there another tool for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborabate on why emma fails for this purpose?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem, as following:

1.Start your Web Service.

2.Copy emma.jar into your home folder.
 
3.Run: java -cp ~/emma.jar emma instr -ip ~/classes -m overwrite –outfile ~/coverage.em 

4.Restart Tomcat: run the shutdown script followed by the startup script in ~/tomcat/bin Wait one minute. 

5.Execute your test(s) for the Web Service you are testing. 

6.Restart Tomcat again. 

7.Run: java -cp ~/emma.jar emma report -r html -in ~/coverage.em  -in ~/tomcat/bin/coverage.ec -Dreport.html.out.file=~/myfile.html